# Scaner Java thread in main

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
   public static void main(String[]args){
       Scanner gogosi = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(gogosi.nextInt()<=0) {

    System.out.print("Error");

        }else if(gogosi.nextInt()<=51){

    System.out.print("Please go take your order");

        }else if(gogosi.nextInt()>=51){

    System.out.print("Your gonna get fat");

        }else{
            System.out.print("Error");
        }
   }
}




Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:10)
```

So.. i don`t see what is wrong, i tried, but didnt find any solutuions, please help?
I scanned the code but it still doesn`t work.
dsfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
sd
f
sdf
sdf
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
sdf
sdfsdsaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Comment: Hi Alex, what's your question?

Comment: How are you running this code? What are your inputs?

Comment: how to make the code work..

Comment: well.. you put a int umber.. and the code selects./ compares, int is named gogosi

Comment: @Alex you should pass runtime arguments from `commandline`.

Comment: Please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51722753/edit)** your post to (1) fix the code's indentation, and (2) describe clearly how you run the code and how it accepts the input numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is well documented in the JavaDocs, you are calling nextInt() without checking if there is even something to read and if there is nothing to read, a NoSuchElementException will be thrown. Make sure there is an integer to read by using hasNextInt():

```
    Scanner gogosi = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (gogosi.hasNextInt()) {
        int i = gogosi.nextInt();
        if (i <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Error");
        } else if (i <= 51) {
            System.out.print("Please go take your order");
        } else if (i >= 51) {
            System.out.print("Your gonna get fat");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Error");
        }
    }

    gogosi.close();
```

Also, you probably (depends on what you want to do) want to be able to enter another input after the first one was unsuccessful. To do this, you can wrap a while-loop around the previous code, for example like that:

```
    Scanner gogosi = new Scanner(System.in);

    // possibility to exit the loop when you enter 0
    boolean exit = false;
    while (gogosi.hasNextInt() && !exit) {
        int i = gogosi.nextInt();
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.print("Exit");
            exit = true;
        } else if (i < 0) {
            System.out.print("Error");
        } else if (i <= 51) {
            System.out.print("Please go take your order");
        } else if (i >= 51) {
            System.out.print("Your gonna get fat");
        }
        // note: else removed because it will never be reached anyway
    }

    gogosi.close();
```

Comment: ok, it solved that problem... now it has no output, litterally it says "no noutput"

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments are stored in the `args` parameter.
See: [Command-Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

> When an application is launched, the runtime system passes the
>   command-line arguments to the application's main method via an array
>   of `Strings`.

If you are passing just one number, then it will be in `args[0]`.
Then you just need to grab it, store it in a variable, then do your comparisons.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {   
     //Scanner gogosi = new Scanner(System.in);
     //int x = gogosi.nextInt();

     int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

     if (x<=0) {
        System.out.print("Error");
     } else if(x<=51) {
        System.out.print("Please go take your order");
     } else if(x>=51) {
        System.out.print("Your gonna get fat");
     } else {
        System.out.print("Error");
     }
  }
```

There is no need for the `Scanner`.